# Biometric or biometrics?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently `biometrics` is the more popular tag, at 4 questions, compared to `biometric` which only has one question. Which <s>is</s> should be the canonical tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it ought to be `biometrics` rather than biometric.

Google brings out `Biometrics` in the first few pages when searched for `Biometric`
[image]

---

Wikipedia redirects from `Biometric` to `Biometrics`

[image]

---

Bing says otherwise, though

[image]

Comment: One is the name, the other is the adjective. I agree however that in tags, the name should be used. Nice research work, though.

Comment: -1 for using JPEG for screenshots: http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/

Comment: @Hello71 help me out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078356/why-is-imgur-uploading-returning-the-image-in-jpeg-instead-of-png-format